# Drawing text with shadow on pixmap with QPainter

Tags: c++, qt, shadow, qpainter

I am working on a project in C++ with Qt, and I am trying to find a way to apply a text shadow when drawing text on a QPixmap using QPainter.

I understand that [QGraphicsDropShadowEffect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsdropshadoweffect.html) is a thing, and I am using in other parts of my project, but I can't for the life of me find a way to apply a QGraphicsEffect when drawing with QPainter on a pixmap. Drawing the same text multiple times with different offsets and opacities doesn't quite cut it.

Are there any ways to do this? 
If not, how could I go about making a function that does it, given a QGraphicsEffect to get the radius and color from?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is directly possible to "draw text with shadow", it is only possible to apply a shadow to something already drawn that would take in an element and use say its alpha channel to calculate the shadow.

You should use composition, either of the final products or during drawing. It should work if you use it on a text element. The other option would be to draw your text in black, apply Gaussian blur and then again draw the text on top of it with the desired offset.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer ddriver, it made me search with some new keywords, which lead me to find a suiting solution for my project.

What I figured out is that you can simply create a QLabel with the text and effects you want (QGraphicsDropShadowEffect, in my case), and render it into a QPixmap using [QWidget::grab()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grab). You can then draw this new pixmap with QPainter as you would any other image, by converting your pixmap to a QImage and using QPainter's drawImage().